# Error in using pcap loop with mysql con as My argument

Tags: mysql, c, packet-sniffers

I want to add the mysql connection with the pcap loop which I am using in the code

```
MYSQL *con;
u_char *my_arguments = con;
pcap_loop(handle, total_packet_count, my_packet_handler, my_arguments);
```

but it is giving error

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
>   [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>           u_char *my_arguments = con;^~~

SO what should I do help is needed please

When I am directly putting value of con in pcap loop like pcap_loop(handle, total_packet_count, my_packet_handler, con); it is showing new error

Error is

> passing argument 4 of ‘pcap_loop’ from incompatible pointer type
>   [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>           pcap_loop(handle, total_packet_count, my_packet_handler, con);
>
> note: expected ‘u_char * {aka unsigned char *}’ but argument is of type ‘MYSQL * {aka struct st_mysql *}’
>            PCAP_API int pcap_loop(pcap_t *, int, pcap_handler, u_char *);

but I want it to be pushed in pcap loop

Answer (score 0):

The "user" argument to `pcap_loop()`, `pcap_dispatch()`, and the callback probably *should* have been defined to be a `void *`, as it's a pointer to some arbitrary data that the callback understands, but it was defined to be a `u_char *` instead.

So you should cast the `MYSQL *` to `u_char *`:

```
pcap_loop(handle, total_packet_count, my_packet_handler, (u_char *)con);
```